# An ion icon on the Mat table row goes into the fixed Mat header when I scroll

Tags: html, css, angular

[When I Scroll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMPVx.png)I have an icon on the angular mat-table row. When I scroll the mat table vertically, the icon on the rows goes into the fixed header and is visible on the header. Can anyone please help to fix the issue.
Before Scroll
Here is my code :

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="deleteIcon">
                <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef><strong></strong>
                </mat-header-cell>
                <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">                 
                  <ion-icon name="trash" class="ion-icon-color" (click)="deleteButtonClicked(row)"></ion-icon> 
                </mat-cell>
              </ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to set the `z-index` of the icons to `1` and from `mat-header-cell` to `2` in css so it will be higher ranked than the icons.